# Model toggle causing rerenders and generated colour changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in which I am rendering a coloured div by generating a random colour on the component itself

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8an5ne?file=App.jsx)

```
import uniqolor from 'uniqolor';

const ColourBlock = ({ handleClick }) => {
  const { color: colour } = uniqolor.random({
    saturation: 40,
    lightness: [60],
  });

  return (
    <div
      style={{ background: colour, color: 'white', width: '100px' }}
      onClick={() => handleClick(colour)}
    >
      {colour}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ColourBlock;
```

I am then triggering a modal by clicking the coloured `div`, however each time I click to toggle and then close my modal, it is rerendering my coloured block component and causing the colour to be recalculated each time.

```
const App = () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(null);

  const toggleModal = useCallback((data) => {
    setModalOpen((prev) => !prev);
    setModalData(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ColourBlock handleClick={toggleModal} />
      {modalOpen && <Modal data={modalData} handleClose={toggleModal} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I understand that it is the `useState` usages in the `App.jsx` that is causing the rerendering of the whole tree underneath it...
Is there a way in which I can structure this such that I don't rerender when I toggle my modal?

As @narzul suggested below, I have even attempted to wrap the `toggleModal` in a `useCallback`, but this doesn't help...